# Не открывается фрейм

Tags: php

Что значит такая штука <!-- NOAD: refresh.zg5.ru/map.php -->
Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это касается HTML'a, то это `<!-- комментарий -->`